# How to determine start of a voice in an audio file using Naudio in c#.net

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, naudio-framework

We are trying to determine the start of the voice in an audio file using NAaudio.

Can you please let me know how we should proceed as we are completely new to NAudio and reading an Audio File?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you trying to eliminate the lead-in silence in a recording or trying to locate voice among other noise?

Comment: @Corey: Thanks for the reply. I am looking to locate voice among other noise... Can you please help me out with the same?

Comment: That depends on the type of noise, but frequency analysis is probably going to be your best bet initially.  Unless there's a big difference in volume between the voice and the noise?